# Parents subscription in children not working

Tags: angular, meteor, typescript

I have some problems with Meteor and Angular2.

I have a parent module called Layout, where I have a header bar with the user name, a left menu with my routing and an empty content on the right for the children.

The left menu works with a Directive to open/close the menu (it add/remove the class 'open' when the user clicks).
Also, in ngOnInit, I have a subscription to get Notifications.

They way that I add the children HTML to the parent template is adding '' inside the layout HTML

This is the routing

```
export const routes: Route[] = [
    {path: '', component: LoginComponent, data: {title: 'Login'}, pathMatch: 'full'},
    {
        path: 'app', component: FullLayoutComponent, data: {title: 'Home'}, canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        children: [
            {path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full'},
            {path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, data: {title: 'Dashboard'}}
        ]
    },
        {
            path: 'employees', component: EmployeesComponent, data: {title: 'Employees'},
            children: [
                {path: '', redirectTo: 'list', pathMatch: 'full'},
                {path: 'list', component: EmployeesListComponent, data: {title: 'List'}},
                {path: 'new', component: EmployeeNewComponent, data: {title: 'New'}},
                {path: 'edit/:empId', component: EmployeeEditComponent, data: {title: 'Edit'}},
                {path: 'view/:empId', component: EmployeeDetailsComponent, data: {title: 'details'}}
            ]
        },
    {path: '**', component: Error404Component, data: {title: 'Error'}}
];
```

Imagine that my user is already logged. If I refresh the page with this url 'http://localhost/#/', it automatically redirects to 'http://localhost/#/app/dashboard' and the Directive and the subscription work as expected.

FullLayout Component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-dashboard',
    template
})
@InjectUser("user")
export class FullLayoutComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    user: Meteor.User;
    private userNotification : Observable<Notification[]>;
    private _userNotificationSub: Subscription;
    public ready: boolean;

    constructor(private router: Router) {}

    ngOnInit()
    {
        this._userNotificationSub = MeteorObservable.subscribe('userNotifications', this.user.profile.empId ).subscribe(
            () => {
                this.userNotification = Notifications.find({}).zone();
                console.log(this.userNotification);
            }
        );
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this._userNotificationSub.unsubscribe();
    }

    logout() {
        var self = this;
        Meteor.logout(function(){
            self.router.navigate(['/']);
        });

    }
}
```

The problem is if the user refresh or navigate directly to 'http://localhost/#/app/', 'http://localhost/#/app/dashboard' or 'http://localhost/#/app/employees/list', I don't know why but the left menu is not working (the click event is working, but It doesn't add or remove the class) and also it is not subscribed to get the notifications.

Obviously, I have subscription also inside all my children.

How can I fix it?

EDIT:

I change the routing to work with this:

```
{path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, data: {title: 'Login'}, pathMatch: 'full'},
    {
        path: '', component: FullLayoutComponent, data: {title: 'Home'}, canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        children: [
            {path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full'},
            {path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, data: {title: 'Dashboard'}},]
    },
    {path: '**', component: Error404Component, data: {title: 'Error'}}
];
```

I'm still having the same problem if I go to /login and then I insert my user and password. It redirects to /dashboard and it doesn't work. But if I refresh on /dashboard, all works perfect.

Login.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-login',
    template
})
@InjectUser("user")
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    loginForm: FormGroup;
    error: string;
    user: Meteor.User;
    public submitted: boolean;
    constructor(private router: Router, private zone: NgZone, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
        Meteor.logout();
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        var self = this;
        this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            email: ['', Validators.required],
            password: ['', Validators.required]
        });
        this.error = '';
    }

    login() {
        var self = this;
        this.submitted = true;
        successLogin('test@test.com', '1234);
    }

    successLogin(email, password)
    {
        Meteor.loginWithPassword(email, password, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                this.zone.run(() => {
                    this.error = err;
                    console.log("error en login With password");
                });
            } else {
                console.log('LoginWithPasword');
                console.log(Meteor.user());
                if(Meteor.user())
                {
                    this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("Error iniciando sesión");
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is about subscriptions and header and left menu but I don't see any of this in your code.

Comment: My question is not about how subscriptions works. The problem is that for any reason, the subscription is not being called when I navigate directly to any children

Comment: @Alberto I don't see anyone saying the question is about how subscriptions work. It is simply related with subscriptions.. __about subscriptions__

Comment: I added the subscription, but that part is not the problem. If you read all, you can see that the problem is about routing. Because navigating to '/' works perfect, but navigating to '/app/dashboard' or '/app', it doesn't.

Comment: @Alberto so in order to investigate the error we need to see the components right? It wasn't included by the time that comment was made and you edited it 6 minutes ago.

Comment: Ok, but I think  that component is not necessary for the problem.

Comment: Did you try to add an autorun inside the subscription like this: `MeteorObservable.subscribe('userNotifications', this.user.profile.empId ).subscribe(() => { MeteorObservable.autorun().zone().subscribe( () => { //your stuff}) });`?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't work.

Comment: The problem should come from the `LoadingService`. Is it a library that you developped ? If it's so, could you please post the `LoadingService` code ?

Comment: I removed it this morning from the project, so it is not the problem. I'm still thinking that it should be a problem of how meteor/angular 2 fires the subscriptions between parent and children. Also, something strange happens with routing, because it doesn't work either if I go to /app

Comment: plz add plnkr so we can check where is the error. put your this.userNotification outside of userNotificationSub . and access its value using this.userNotification.subscribe((data)=>{});

Comment: I can't belive I'm the first one with this problem. This is a problem with angular routing. If I go to /login, it redirects to / and it doesn't work, but if I refresh, it goes directly to / because the user is already logged in, and it works...

Comment: I edited the question adding another example. When I log in, it doesn't work, but refreshing having the Meteor.user all is working as expected